# renamed sql database now unable to connect

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an sql database which earlier I connected to no problem using this code:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","user192","xxxx") or die ("couldnt connect to sql"); 
$db=mysql_select_db ("sound-library",$con) or die ("cant find database");
?>
```

The strange this is that I tried renaming the database to something else in phpmyadmin and updating the name in the msql_select_db line but it didn't work. Because it didn't work I tried renaming it back to sound-library and again updating the msql_select_db line (ie so that it was like I had it before renaming) and now it says I get the cant find database message. This makes no sense as im reverting back to exactly what I had before and its not finding the db! Is there something that could have happened in renaming it in phpmyadmin that is not visible in the db names that are shown on the left?

Comment: MySQL does not really support renaming schemas; they did for a short while, but quickly removed the feature after it caused too many issues.

Comment: oh ok, not sure why they have that option then. Guess I have to start over on the db?

Comment: Well, I did see something about altering databases (add around or soon after renaming them was removed), but it seems like that was more intended for server upgrades, not general administration. But all that depends on the version MySQL you are running. It is possible that however it is being renamed is a long process that has yet to complete...

Comment: Managed to resolve this. Turns out you need to re-add the mysql users in the mysql databases panel as it won't carry these over once renamed

Comment: Strange, I could see there being permission issues with existing users not having rights to the new schema, but since mysql users are stored in a different schema `mysql` I wouldn't think they would need added all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this. Turns out you need to re-add the mysql users in the mysql databases panel as it won't carry these over once renamed